# Property not loading straightaway EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a `Request` class containing a property `CreatedBy` of the type `ApplicationUser`.

I then need to do some authorization to see if the request is accessible by the current user, like so:

```
public bool HasAccessToRequest(Request req)
{
    var user = GetCurrentUser();

    if (req == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (req.CreatedBy.Department.Managers.Any(x => x.Id == user.Id))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Where `GetCurrentUser()` just get's the currently logged in user as an object.

The issue is, when I do this I get an error:

> “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

This is verifiable by stepping through this block of code and I notice that when breakpointing, `CreatedBy` is indeed not loaded. Then I look to my db table and there is a valid value there, so I try again but this time waiting for about 5 seconds and then it magically appears in the `req` parameter upon hovering over.

I'm not using any sort of `async` methods and I have this same method in a different controller which is working totally fine. Any pointers on what it could be? As far as I know there is no other code that is running before hand that I need to wait for, I can just see that this is taking a while to load and without setting a breakpoint and waiting I get the above error.

First this happens:

[image]

Then after waiting for 2-4 seconds this happens:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had lazy loading disabled for `CreatedBy` so making it:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

Seemed to fix the issue. This is a little bit confusing because I'm more than half way through the development of this project and this field never needed to be virtualised before and worked completely fine, and I'm not sure if it could cause potential problems later on.